# Video Editing Freeware for Professional Effects

Tags: gratis, video-editing, youtube, gopro

I've got a YouTube channel where I upload short-film made with my GoPro Hero 3+. I sometimes put some effect, but when I do, thy always looks ugly because I use Camtasia Studio for editing and chroma key. I also tryed Adobe After Effect CC 2014 Free Trail and I have to say that it was really good and professional. Now I'm using HitFilm 3 Pro Demo, but with the Demo I can't export my video, and that's what I need. Because before posting it on YouTube, I want to save a copy on my PC.

I looked for a good software on the web, but I didn't find anything.

I need a software that could:

1. Apply good Chroma Key
2. Apply already made effects
3. Exports directly on YouTube and Save on the PC

Can you reccomend me some software?

Sorry for my bad English, I'm Italian